# 404 not found - IIS 7.5 (sub-application)

Tags: api, controller, iis-7.5, http-get, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a main application (Toolbox-GUI) and a sub application (Toolbox-WPS) deployed on IIS 7.5.

The Api under sub-application is giving 404 not found *when deployed on server*.

When run Locally(localhost) it works fine. I am using .netcore

Both have different application pools. both application pools are set at .net framework version 4.0/ApplicationPoolIdentity.

The main project works fine.

### **Toolbox-WPS (subapplication)**

```
[Route("wps/status/{id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetStatusRecord(long id)
    {
        // returns the status document for a given status id
        //logger.Debug("GET wps/status/" + id);
        
    }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
        //services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSingleton<ISingleton, WPSGlobalSettings2>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        WPSGlobalSettings.Configure(env);
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                // added the web api to a specified url/wps publish path, so can remove this here.
                pattern: "{controller}/{id}"
                //defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );
        });
    }
```

**Toolbox-GUI (main app)**

```
function poll_check() {
$.ajax({
    url: pollStatusUri,
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
        // if (debugState) console.log("polling at " + pollStatusUri);

        
    },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

[image]

IIS Configuration

main app

[image]

sub app

[image]

project hierarchy

[image]

**application pools**

main app

[image]
sub app
[image]

Comment: Edit the question and show your IIS configuration please.

Comment: I have added it..also the bindings show port as 80

Comment: You should test what's the response for `https://<hostname>/wps/wps/status/<id>`.

Comment: Yes!! this one works :D...I feel so silly so how do I change to make it 1 wps\

Comment: Also if you add answer i can mark it as correct

Comment: I would like to inform you that the IIS 7.5 is an older version of the IIS and it is out of support now. Further, I notcied that you have 1 main app and 1 sub app with separate app pool and you are using using .net framework version 4.0. For .Net Core app you could try to select **No Managed code** option. Also, you could trt to install [.NetCore](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet) runtime for your .Net Core app.

Comment: @LexLi how would i go back to https://<hostname>/wps/status/<id>...?

Comment: Change `[Route("wps/status/{id}")]` to `[Route("status/{id}")]`

Comment: That can't be an option..otherwise it stops working locally...any iis settings change?